# localhost:3000 unable to connect but ip is fine

Tags: linux, macos, npm, terminal

I use create-react-app to create project **on mac**, after running npm start I can see the success message in the terminal, but somehow I can't run localhost:3000, I have to use the ip as alternative, what's wrong? I tried on different machine it worked, so it's my mac's config issue.

Comment: Can you share the the output of `sudo cat /private/etc/hosts`?

Comment: I don't have private directory.

Comment: Then you don't have a Mac. More likely, you are not actually trying that command literally, or mistyping it.